# Create chart using mysql data base for today, weekly, monthly and between two date

Tags: php, mysql, select

I am using mysql for my data base. I have created analytic detail in a table. I want to show that data in a chart. I have created data on click in specific link and the date time saved in database.
Table is like

```
id | datetime
-------------
1  | 2016-04-18 05:26:36
2  | 2016-04-18 07:26:36
3  | 2016-04-18 09:26:36
4  | 2016-04-18 11:26:36
5  | 2016-04-18 08:26:36
6  | 2016-04-18 05:26:36
7  | 2016-04-18 20:26:36
8  | 2016-04-18 18:26:36
```

I want to show data as based on hour for today like

```
hour | click
---------------
1    | 0
2    | 0
3    | 0
4    | 0
5    | 2
6    | 0
7    | 1
8    | 1
9    | 1
10   | 0
11   | 1
12   | 0
13   | 0
14   | 0
15   | 0
16   | 0
17   | 0
18   | 1
19   | 0
20   | 1
21   | 0
22   | 0
23   | 0
24   | 0
```

Similarly for weekly where weekday(Sunday,Monday,Tuesday...Saturday) instead of hour, week number (1,2,3,4,5...... 28/29/30/31) for monthly detail.

I have used a query for today list but it give only the hour name where the data is present. I need all hour list with fill 0 if there in no value in that hour.

I am using this query.

```
SELECT DISTINCT(hour(`beacon_date_time`)) as hour,COUNT(*) from beaconanalytics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP by hour(`beacon_date_time`)
```

I am using query for seven day but it is also give the record for the day in database not for show 0 for remaining days.

This is the query.

```
SELECT dayname(`beacon_date_time`) as hour,COUNT(*) from beaconanalytics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP by dayname(`beacon_date_time`)
```

Comment: I would just fill these zeros in `php` code. For example, you have an array `hours[1-24]` with all values initialized to 0. Then you use your query and overwrite some hours with data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, look like a little weird;)

```
SELECT tmp.hour, sum(tmp.click) AS click
FROM
  (SELECT DISTINCT
    (hour(`beacon_date_time`)) AS hour,
    COUNT(*) AS click
  FROM beaconanalytics
  WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`, '%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),
                                                                        '%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(), '%Y-%m-%d')
  GROUP BY hour(`beacon_date_time`)
  UNION
  SELECT 1 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 2 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 3 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 4 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 5 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 6 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 7 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 8 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 9 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 10 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 11 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 12 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 13 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 14 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 15 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 16 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 17 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 18 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 19 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 20 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 21 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 22 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 23 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual
  UNION
  SELECT 24 AS hour, 0 AS click FROM dual) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.hour
```

Try this for weekly;)

```
SELECT tmp.dayname, sum(tmp.click) AS click
FROM
  (SELECT dayname(`beacon_date_time`) as dayname,COUNT(*) AS click from beaconanalytics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP by dayname(`beacon_date_time`)
   UNION
   SELECT 'Monday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Tuesday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Wednesday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Thursday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Friday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Saturday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
   UNION
   SELECT 'Sunday' AS dayname, 0 AS click FROM dual
  ) tmp
GROUP BY tmp.dayname
```

Comment: And for monthly even more selects. What if he will decide to do a yearly report or for decade? :D

Comment: @akasummer what you've told is worrying about the performance of this query?-.-

Comment: What I've told is giving a hint that your solution is definitely not the way to go.

Comment: @akasummer Yes,that's it, my solution may not be the way to go, hmm...  I've just consider it as a pure sql question.

Comment: Similarly i have created query for weekly data. This is also give the result where the data belong but not show 0 for remaining days. Query is ::- SELECT dayname(`beacon_date_time`) as hour,COUNT(*) from beaconanalytics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 7 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP by dayname(`beacon_date_time`)

Comment: @SatanandTiwari I've update my answer, you can check if it works or not.

Comment: okay... thanks man. please give me the last fever for month also because there are fixed count for hour and week but there are differences in month days. like 28 for Feb, 29 for leap year, 30 and 31 days in corresponding month.

Comment: @SatanandTiwari  I suppose you figure it out by yourself, or understand my sql for daily at least. As akasummer said, I've just give you a sql, not a hint.:D- Though there are differences in month days, you also can use 31 days cause you just need a counted result. Even Feb does not have 29 or 30 or 31, these three day's click time is 0, it has some seriously matter?

Answer (score 0):

Please try

```
 SELECT days.daynum, IF(count.c IS NULL, 0, count.c) from 
        (
        SELECT t*10+u daynum
        FROM
            (SELECT 0 t UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3) A,
            (SELECT 0 u UNION SELECT 1 UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3
            UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
            UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9) B
        ORDER BY daynum
        ) as days
        LEFT JOIN 
        (
        SELECT DISTINCT(hour(`beacon_date_time`)) as hour,COUNT(*) as c from beaconanalytics WHERE DATE_FORMAT(`beacon_date_time`,'%Y-%m-%d') BETWEEN DATE_FORMAT(DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY),'%Y-%m-%d') AND DATE_FORMAT(NOW(),'%Y-%m-%d') GROUP by hour(`beacon_date_time`)
        ) as count ON count.hour = days.daynum ORDER BY days.daynum
```

Comment: This show 39 record. Previous answer is good for 24 hours record. but now the question is for weekly data where i want Sunday, Monday... Saturday instead of  1,2,3.....24.

Comment: Okay can you please update your question as well @SatanandTiwari